Is mounting a sloped photovoltaic panel on a wall of a building a bad idea?
I live in an apartment building in which I don't have access to the roof, but I do have quite a bit of accessible space on the building's Southern wall. I should add: I'm most interested in mounting the panel such that it has a slope of 40 degrees, not vertically.
I was looking for resources on how to install a panel on a wall, and I was surprised how little info and products are there. One example: In the Photovoltaic Design & Installation for dummies book, in Chapter 16, there is not even a mention of a mount on a wall.
I don't want to list out any particular products here, but suffice it say that even when I do find a seemingly suitable wall mount, I can't confirm what is the maximum allowable weight for the panel.
Initially, I thought that a panel mounted to a wall at a slope is a great idea. It wouldn't heat up as much as one mounted on the roof, it allows for easier maintenance (at least in my case), and I was expecting more additional power could be generated when using a bifacial panel.
This leads me to the suspicion that, for some reason, mounting a PV panel to a wall of a building is a bad idea. But I was hoping anyone here could give me reasons for why that might be?

These are usually referred to as solar "awnings" or "canopies" and they're certainly an installation approach people take.

That broadens the result space, thank you!

I do not fully understand slope. Do you mean at an angle? Or with variable angle? But so most roof (and green field) panels are installed at an angle, but if you are near equator. The problem is more on building code: fire protection (depend on wall), strength of wall (consider also winds), snow and water (and shadow) falling on other apartments.

I wasn't sure if "slope" is the right word here. I meant: The angle between the surface of the PV panel and the horizontal plane. So, yes, I meant having the panel at an angle with respect to the wall, and not just "hanging" on the wall's surface.
